# Space spanned by linearly dependent rows

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have the following matrix, then the row space of A is the subspace spanned by $\{r_1, r_2, r_3\}$ and it's row space is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since the second row is a linear combination of the first row, does this change the dimension of the subspace that the rows span.

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: There are only two rows, right, so no $r_3$. And the answer to your question is yes. Can you actually explicitly tell us what the row space is in this case? Is it a line, a plane, or all of $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: The dimension of the subspace is the number of linearly independent vectors that span it. Here there is only one.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right, there are only two rows. But each row has 3 entires. The vector `[1, 1, 1]` is a point in 3-space right?